# Is it possible to get a hash of an anonymous routine's implementation?

Tags: delphi

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  MyAnonymousProcedure : TProc;
begin
  //assign an anonymous procedure to a variable.
  MyAnonymousProcedure := procedure
  begin
    Foo;
  end;
  MyAnonymousProcedure(); //Call the newly assigned procedure.



  // do the same thing again but with a different anonymous method.
  MyAnonymousProcedure := procedure
  begin
    Bar;
  end;
  MyAnonymousProcedure();
end;
```

In the above code there are two anonymous procedures. They are assigned to the same TProc variable in turn. The code in each anonymous procedure is clearly different. Is there a way to find the *executable code* that the `MyAnonymousProcedure` variable references? I guess that would be a memory location. From there is it possible to then calculate the hash of the *executable code* found at that memory location?

Comment: Maybe I've been living under a rock for 20 years, but what do you mean "calculate the hash"? Do you mean you'd like to run the source code for that procedure through some sort of checksum algorithm? Could you please explain why. I'm certainly open to learning new things, and I'm curious.

Comment: "Do you mean you'd like to run the source code for that procedure through some sort of checksum algorithm?" Yep, exactly.

Comment: Interesting, but *why*? (just curious)

Comment: In this case I would like to do it as part of writing a Debounce function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433336/how-to-write-a-debounce-procedure-in-delphi It also might be useful in copy protection routines to ensure a procedure hasn't been patched.

Comment: You're trying to get an identifier for an anonymous function. Note that hashing only the executable code won't be enough. You'll also need to include the captured variables. For example, consider the [`MakeAdder` example from the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi). The code portion of the method returned by `MakeAdder(1)` will obviously be the same as the code from `MakeAdder(2)`, but their captured variables have different values, so they shouldn't be judged to be identical.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to find the executable code that the
>   `MyAnonymousProcedure` variable references?

There is always "a way" but it is tricky in this case.

First an anonymous method can be treated as a reference to interface with a single `Invoke` method as explained by [Barry Kelly](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/using-anonymous-methods-in-method.html).

Applying the idea to your code we get:

```
procedure MethRefToProcPtr(const MethRef; var ProcPtr);
type
  TVtable = array[0..3] of Pointer;
  PVtable = ^TVtable;
  PPVtable = ^PVtable;
begin
  // 3 is offset of Invoke, after QI, AddRef, Release
  TMethod(ProcPtr).Code := PPVtable(MethRef)^^[3];
end;
```

Unfortunately the `ProcPtr` value returned is not what you probably want - it is an address of a stub code that fixes an interface reference (converts an interface reference to an object reference) and jumps to the address we are looking for. If you trace the code pointed by `ProcPtr` you will find something like this (Delphi XE, 32-bits):

```
     add eax,-$10
     jmp FooBar
```

and at the `FooBar` address you will find

```
     call Foo
```

or

```
     call Bar
```

dependent of the current value of your anonymous method.

I guess the only way to get the `FooBar` address now is to parse the assembler `jmp` instruction.

---

Here is the code I used for my experiments:

```
procedure Foo;
begin
  Writeln('Foo');
end;

procedure Bar;
begin
  Writeln('Bar');
end;

procedure MethRefToProcPtr(const MethRef; var ProcPtr);
type
  TVtable = array[0..3] of Pointer;
  PVtable = ^TVtable;
  PPVtable = ^PVtable;
begin
  // 3 is offset of Invoke, after QI, AddRef, Release
  TMethod(ProcPtr).Code := PPVtable(MethRef)^^[3];
end;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  MyAnonymousProcedure : TProc;
  MyProc : procedure;

begin
  //assign an anonymous procedure to a variable.
  MyAnonymousProcedure := procedure
  begin
    Foo;
  end;
//  MyAnonymousProcedure(); //Call the newly assigned procedure.

  MethRefToProcPtr(MyAnonymousProcedure, MyProc);
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@MyProc]));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@Foo]));
  MyProc;

  // do the same thing again but with a different anonymous method.
  MyAnonymousProcedure := procedure
  begin
    Bar;
  end;
//  MyAnonymousProcedure();

  MethRefToProcPtr(MyAnonymousProcedure, MyProc);
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@MyProc]));
  Writeln(Format('%p', [@Bar]));
  MyProc;
end;
```

Comment: This only works in your case. Anonymous methods are called methods because they are methods. So they consist of a code and a data pointer. Which is important when you capture variables (which is why the stub method does the add eax - to change the interface reference, which anonymous methods are under the hood to the compiler generated object reference behind the scenes).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer here is a routine that converts the compiler generated method stub that fixes the eax to the "real" method of the compiler generated class for the anonymous method.

```
procedure MethodStubToMethod(const Method; var Result);
var
  offset: ShortInt;
begin
  offset := PByte(TMethod(Method).Code)[2];
  TMethod(Result).Code := PByte(TMethod(Method).Code) + 3;
  TMethod(Result).Data := PByte(TMethod(Method).Data) + offset;
end;
```

It's a simple and naive implementation that assumes that the offset will never get bigger than one byte (which only would happen if you have hundred different anonymous methods within the same routine (like you have 2 in the original source in the question).

It assumes the layout of the stub is like this (which it for anonymous methods afaik)

```
add eax, offset
jmp address
```

Then you can write:

```
procedure MethRefToProcPtr(const MethRef; var ProcPtr);
type
  TVtable = array[0..3] of Pointer;
  PVtable = ^TVtable;
  PPVtable = ^PVtable;
begin
  // 3 is offset of Invoke, after QI, AddRef, Release
  TMethod(ProcPtr).Code := PPVtable(MethRef)^^[3];
  TMethod(ProcPtr).Data := Pointer(MethRef);
end;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  MyAnonymousProcedure: TProc;
  Method: procedure of object;
begin
  //assign an anonymous procedure to a variable.
  MyAnonymousProcedure := procedure
  begin
    Foo;
  end;
  MyAnonymousProcedure(); //Call the newly assigned procedure.
  MethRefToProcPtr(MyAnonymousProcedure, Method); //
  Method(); //same as calling the anonymous method
  MethodStubToMethod(Method, Method)
  Method(); // now we are calling the method directly on the object     
end;
```